# I'm facing issue in Salesforce Classic Home Page Narrow Component in Subscriber Org

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component, salesforce-classic

I have a managed package which includes Salesforce Classic UI HomePage Component display Visualforce page.

Now it's not working in any subscriber org. if we copy the page URL by using inspect the element and open the page URL in new tab its work fine but visual force page not working on Home Page Component may be due to Salesforce Security Patches.

I tried with Html home page component but it's showing the iframe code instead of rendering the visual force page any workaround?

Comment: Does the profile have permission to the VF page? You may like to review if the permissions were impacted because of [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000001SHDl) that occurred last week.

Comment: yes profile is the system administrator and if I open the page in new tab its working fine